# How to Parallel.For in C# in a nested for

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, nested, parallel.for

the true is I'm new with parallelism, but I want to learn how to implement it, so I want to run a Parallel.For in the next code:

```
colFrom = CountColumns(auxws);
colTo = CountColumns(ws);
rowFrom = CountRows(auxws);
rowTo = CountRows(ws);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
//Parallel.For( --I dont know what to write here --
for ( i = 1; i <= rowFrom; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <=colFrom ; j++){
         ws.Cells[i, j] = auxws.Cells[i, j].Value; 
    }         
});
```

The thing is that I have a huge excel file that I need to copy to another file, and right now with out the Parallel.For it takes around 20 minutes to iterate it all.

So I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to modify an Excel sheet, don't. Excel interop isn't thread-safe. Even if you use a library like EPPlus there's no guarantee `Cells` is thread-safe unless the author of the library explicitly says it is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider reading information about [Aksing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition, what have you tried so far?

Comment: How many rows are there anyway? Even with a full 1M rows transposing cells shouldn't take that long **UNLESS** you are use Excel interop. In this case a) each get/set is a cross-process call hence *slow* and b) transposing is already available.

Comment: Assuming you are using Excel interop, start recording a macro and transpose the selected cells. The recorded macro uses the same API as Excel interop which means you can copy the methods used.

Comment: Check the [Transpose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.transpose?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_WorksheetFunction_Transpose_System_Object_). I suspect that's what the macro uses too

Comment: You likely would not see a performance benefit to using parallel programming, you could spin up multiple threads but you will still be locked by the disk IO.  If you were reading hitting a web service, reading a file, then inputting to a database at the same time that would be a valid use case.  But to use parallel programming to read a single file faster, is not.